# Django app ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when adding custom middleware to settings.py

Tags: python, django, middleware

I've created a LoggedInUserMiddleware in my project/app/middleware.py file and added it as the last entry in the MIDDLEWARE portion of my project/master/settings.py file. Before adding it to settings.py the app responds just fine.  After adding it to settings.py i get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from any url of my app.

My LoggedInUserMiddleware currently looks like this just to try to get it to not crash things.

```
class LoggedInUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        return None
```

As I understand it, that middleware should execute with every single new html request, but do absolutely nothing.

Comment: As an aside, what do you want you `LoggedInUserMiddleware` to do? Make sure you aren't duplicating the functionality of the built in authentication middleware!

Comment: If an anonymous user requests any of my urls I want the middleware to redirect to the login url.  I just realized that the links i was following to https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/middleware/ are, like you said, out of date!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written an [old-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/) (Django < 1.10). If you are using the `MIDDLEWARE` setting instead of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, then you should write a [new-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/).

One option is to use the [`MiddlewareMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware).

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class LoggedInUserMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        return None
```

However, if you do not need to support the old `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting, there is no need to use the mixin, and I would start from the example in the docs:

```
class LoggedInUserMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```